# XAML collection of interface/abstract "Could not create an instance"

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, collections, abstract

I have in the *ViewModel* an `ObservableCollection<INode>` where `INode` is an interface.

The *View XAML* is like:

```
<Windows x:Class="XXX.Window1"
         xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:XXX.Views" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModels" 
         xmlns:n="clr-namespace:XXX.Models.Nodes"
         ... />
    ...
    <vm:MyView>
        <vw:MyView.DataContext>
            <vm:MyViewModel>
                <vm:ComponentViewModel.Nodes>
                    <n:MyNode />                <--- PROBLEM HERE
                    <n:MyNode />
                </vm:ComponentViewModel.Nodes>
            </vm:MyViewModel>
        </vw:MyView.DataContext>
    </vm:MyView>
    ...
```

Now this works at runtime, but not in the *design* time window which shows: 
**Could not create an instance of type 'MyNode'**

Any idea how to solve this?

---

```
interface INode
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    string Status { get; }
}

abstract class Node : INode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract string Status { get; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();     // <--- PROBLEM WAS HERE, Name = null
        }
    }
}

class MyNode : Node
{
    public override NodeStatus Status { get { return "test"; } }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `MyNode` and the full stack trace and error message of that design time exception.

Comment: MyNode is a concrete implementation of INode. I cannot give the stack trace as it's a design time error. Meaning when viewing the XAML in Visual Studio.

Comment: Please show the code of `MyNode`. It's impossible to say what the problem is without the code. Most likely it's constructor throws an exception.

Comment: MyNode will need a default constructor to operate in the designer.  Please also show us the xmlns import for "n".

Comment: I removed the constructor of MyNode to have only the default one. In case of exception, there is another error usually displayed: The exception itself. But I'll add more details.

Comment: Can you see the InnerException? Does it work if you make the MyNode class (and its constructor) public?

Comment: Public didn't change a thing. It's really bad that VS doesn't show the details of such exceptions happening when editing the XAML, but I finally pined it down.

Answer (score 0):

Each case seem to be unique. Here's what I learned after solving it: Not only an exception in the constructor can generate that error message. If some system methods like `GetHashCode()` throw and exception, it'll display that same message (some times at design-time *only*).

Other people may have more tips or more insight VS design-time flow.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it is not a XAML problem, but happens because you are not setting the Name property. When GetHashCode is called it will fail because you are calling a method on a null reference.

Try adding your node as

```
<n:MyNode Name="blah" />
```

Comment: Yes I saw that and it's fixed now. However it was set, just it wasn't set when that property got called in design-time.